# Action Script 3 URLLoader in for loop

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, addeventlistener, urlloader

I have 7 Arrays to begin with:

```
private var listArray:Array = new Array();
private var oneArray:Array = new Array();
private var twoArray:Array = new Array();
private var threeArray:Array = new Array();
private var fourArray:Array = new Array();
private var fiveArray:Array = new Array();
private var sixArray:Array = new Array();
```

listArray contain 6 string element of text file name.
something like:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt
```

All other array is empty at the moment.

I have wrote a for loop like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < listArray.length; i++)
{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(listArray[i]).url);
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    try
    {
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    }catch (error:Error){
        trace("Cannot load : " + error.message);
    }
}
```

if without for loop I know I can do this for only one array of data:

```
private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
{
    oneArray = e.target.data.split(/\r\n/);
}
```

Here I am trying to get something to work like:

oneArray contain the data from 1.txt

twoArray contain the data from 2.txt

so on...

sixArray contain the data from 6.txt

problem:

I known the completeHandler function only execute after for loop looped six times.

is there anyway I could get the correct data to the correct array.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if my problem is not clear at the end, English is my second language .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using AIR to load data from the file-system, you don't have to do it asynchronously. You can load it synchronously like this:

```
function readTxtList(url:String):Array {
    var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(url);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var text:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    fileStream.close();
    return text.split("\r\n");
}
```

Now you can just assign each value directly:

```
var oneArray:Array = readTxtList("1.txt");
var twoArray:Array = readTxtList("2.txt");
// etc
```

Comment: This work very well and much easier than how I was thinking.
Thanks a lot, Aaron

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Dictionary.

Create new Dictionary:

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
```

Bind an instance of the URLLoader class to the file name:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = ...
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
dict[urlLoader] = listArray[i];
```

In the `completeHandler` you can get the file name:

```
trace(dict[e.currentTarget]);
```

Add `if` statements to reach your goal.

```
if (dict[e.currentTarget] == "1.txt")
    oneArray = e.target.data.split(/\r\n/);
else if (dict[e.currentTarget] == "2.txt")
    twoArray = e.target.data.split(/\r\n/);
...
```